# Esxi Host - can't access via hostname anymore

Tags: networking, dns, esxi, hostname

Having had to reset router (Google Nest Wifi) i'm now unable to access my home esxi server via hostname. (I can still access it via local IP)

and nslookup of it's ip returns

```
>nslookup 192.168.86.103
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.86.1

*** UnKnown can't find 192.168.86.103: Non-existent domain
```

Whereas a working server where i can access via host name returns

```
>nslookup 192.168.86.102
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.86.1

Name:    mainserver2.lan
Address:  192.168.86.102
```

I can access hostnames from any device on my local network.

The content of the esxi hosts file is

```
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.86.103  esxi.lan esxi
```

Am at loss as to why this has stopped working. Is there anything missing from my hosts file? I was able to access it aok before, nothing has been changed in Esxi from my end. I can also access all Esxi vms by hostname etc.

Comment: Don't change anything on the hosts file, or your network - the problem will exist within the google home wifi. Has the domain prefix (.lan) changed to something else? I'm also assuming that the esxi has it's IP set manually? - Try setting it to DHCP temporarily and see what the nslookup says once you know it's IP

Comment: from here it appears .lan is fixed https://support.google.com/googlenest/thread/2062751/how-do-you-configure-a-dns-suffix?hl=en esxi is set to DHCP. So i'm currently at a loss.

Comment: reset the esxi network adapter - you have to do this directly on the esxi server. There should be an option to reset.

Comment: Gave this a go via the exsi main interface and unbelievably still no dice. Will reset the router next but it's quite a big job given all the port forwarding I have going on.

Comment: If you have a spare network card for your esxi, plug that in and use it as the main. Will save you resetting the router. Personally, by now I would of replaced the google router.